# Asp.net Chat without timer

Tags: asp.net, ajax, chat

I have Problem with chat application .
**my scenario:**
I need to build chat application with web application as a service .
I need a chat application without a timer when a first client send message to secound client the message should appeare on a first client whitout using timer 
my techniques : asp.net mvc and jquery 
I found this [Chat Application in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1693100/chat-application-in-asp-net)
but how to solve this problem technical in asp.net mvc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at websockets in the asp.net 4.5 developer preview or SignalR project

Comment: my problem is how to send message without getajax data using timer